# Unable to fetch data for updating a record using php

Tags: php

Trying to update a record unable to fetch the data from database.Getting a blank page not getting any data from database.

```
<?php
include 'includes/db.php';
$id = (int)$_GET['appoint_id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE appoint_id = '$id'";
$run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
    $firstname = $row['first_name'];
    $lastname = $row['last_name'];        
}   
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="update.php" method="post" role="form">
    <input  type='hidden' value='<?=$id;?>' name='appoint_id'>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['first_name'];?>" name="first_name" id="first_name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['last_name'];?>" name="last_name" id="last_name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

update.php

```
<?php include 'includes/db.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit_user'])){
        $ins_sql = "UPDATE first_name,last_name appointment  WHERE appoint_id = '$id' ";
        $run_sql = mysqli_query($conn,$ins_sql);
    }else {
        echo "not updated";
    }
 ?>
```

Not displaying any errors in error log as well.

Comment: You never check for errors thats why you do not get any. Read about syntax of update statements

Comment: If you do a @Jens tells you, you will learn at least that your update syntax is wrong for every database I came accross.

Comment: The proper `update` syntax is `UPDATE TABLE SET column = value, column2 = value2 WHERE some condition`. You also should parameterize your query. This is injectable.

Comment: You never set `$id` in `update.php`.

Comment: There's no `name="submit_user"` anywhere in the form.

Comment: The `while` loop keeps overwriting the same variables. You're only getting the values from the last row that was fetched from the table. If it only fetches one row, you don't need a loop at all.

Comment: @user3783243 to update we need to display the data in the fields after clicking on edit button but the data is not diplayng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
?php session_start();
include 'includes/db.php';  
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE appoint_id = $id";
$oppointArr =array();
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {          
       $oppointArr = $row;
       echo "Name: " . $row["first_name"]. "<br>";
      }
  } else {
  echo "0 results";
 }
//mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

Query for fetching the data for a particular record

Answer (score 0):

`update.php` has incorrect syntax for the `UPDATE` query, and it's not using any of the form parameters (except for one that doesn't even exist in the form, `$_POST['submit_user']`).

You should use a prepared statement to protect against SQL injection.

```
<?php
include 'includes/db.php';
$ins_sql = "UPDATE appointment
            SET first_name = ?, last_name = ?
            WHERE appoint_id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($ins_sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['appoint_id']);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "updated";
} else {
    echo "not updated";
}
```

Comment: To update i need to get the data from database right but not getting any data in the fields it is displaying blank form